# Python 3.4.3 asyncio keywords SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Terminal output is worth a thousand words, I guess

```
[~] $ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jun 22 2016, 16:03:29)
[GCC 4.9.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
>>> async def fun():
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    async def fun():
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async` and `await` syntax was introduced in Python 3.5. (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutines)

In Python 3.4 you need to use the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator and `yield from` syntax. (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines)

Answer (score 1):

The `async` keyword was added in Python 3.5.